# Is it possible to communicate tomcat server with certificate expired SMTP server while sending mail using spring?

Tags: java, spring-security, smtp, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail

I've used email service to send the email to users, using spring mail. I've configured bean in this way

Error message is given below:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:308)


<bean id="mailService" class="media4u.sr.util.MailService">
    <property name="mailSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
            <property name="host" value="178-77-77-162.kundenadmin.hosteurope.de"/>

            <property name="password" value="XXX"/>
            <property name="username" value="srowdies@media4u.org"/>

            <property name="javaMailProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property> 
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="resourceBundleBaseName" value="messages" />
    <property name="confirmationLinkTarget" value="http://178.77.77.162:8080/srweb/confirm.htm" />
    <property name="confirmationSenderName" value="StrassenRowdies" />
</bean>
```

While using google mail it works properly. but at the time of configuring my companys email server it produced the following errors:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've gone through a lots of blog and solution and came to know that the SMTP servers Certification has already been expired.
[image]

On the other side my client doesn't want to use others email server and told me for the time being due to unable to renew their certificate, use some shorts of mechanisum for instance unsecured way so that we can use their SMTP mail server.

And I came to know that there is self signed certificate mechanisam too but I want to make sure that whether this mechanism is working or not and how to do this?

Comment: I've tested that given email account credentials by using outlook, however its working properly

Answer (score 0):

If you trust this expired or self-signed certificate, you can add it to your trust store.  The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) tells you how to do that.

You can also choose to ignore the certificate for this host by setting the [mail.smtp.ssl.trust](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.trust) property.